# How to keep track of whether all strings in a list have a specific string present in them?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have a list of strings within which I need to search for a specific sub-string and return a result only when the sub-string is present in every string that is in the list. My first idea was to create a list of boolean values that correspond with whether the sub-string is present in each larger string in my list, and then write another loop to check whether this list of booleans is True at every index. Does anybody have any suggestions for a more elegant and efficient method?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: A single list comprehension should do it.

Comment: [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) should help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
l = ["pie", "lie", "die"]
all( ['ie' in x for x in l] )
```

The above version may perform [unnecessary checks](http://cis.poly.edu/cs1114/pyLecturettes/short-circuit-eval.html).

```
all( 'ie' in x for x in l )
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of listcomp prevents short-circuiting.

Comment: I edited the answer, now I have to search about short-circuiting :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function along with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to avoid creating a throw-away intermediate list. Since the code can be expressed as one line, I'd also define it using a [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) instead of the usual `def function()`:

```
# define function via lambda
in_all = lambda strings, specific: all(specific in strng for strng in strings)
in_all.__doc__ = """ Check whether all strings in list contain specified string. """

l1 = ["day", "lay", "may"]
l2 = ["day", "lay", "may", "not"]

print(in_all(l1, "ay"))  # -> True (all had specific string)
print(in_all(l2, "ay"))  # -> False (at least one didn't have
                         #           the specific string)
```

Comment: Using a lambda and then immediately naming it is usually disfavoured anyway, but then manually using a dunder to document it?  Why not just use ordinary function syntax?

Comment: I don't disfavor using lamdas to define short functions, but your point about the doc string is valid. I just threw that in for no good reason—mostly just to show that the object was a function—most folks probably don't ever bother and most short functions don't need one.